# Unable to display image in tkinter after opening it with PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to get tkinter to open an image selected by the user from a the file browser prompt and display it on the canvas. I plan to edit this image later so I'm using PIL to edit and support other file types. However, when I try to display the image, nothing shows up and no errors are thrown. I don't really know why this is so. I think it might be because Image is a module name shared in both tkinter and PIL but I don't know for sure.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
img = Image.open(
    filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select file", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*"))))
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img), anchor=NW)
canvas.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you think it's an issue with naming of the module, maybe try `from PIL import ImageTk, Image as Im` or something. Although I doubt that's the case, I think it's worth a short.

Comment: When you say nothing shows up, is that literally what happens with the _exact_ code you posted? There are issues when working with images in a function, but you don't seem to be using a function.

Comment: The `ImageTk.PhotoImage` created is immediately deleted because it screation is being done only to be passed as an argument in the `canvas.cread_image()` call. Create it on a separate line and give it a variable name.

Comment: @martineau Thanks, it works now!

Comment: James: Glad you were able to  decipher my too-hastily written comment. `;¬)`

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you split the line

```
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img), anchor=NW)
```

into 2 separate lines

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)
```

would work, I am not sure why but it is a quick fix.

Comment: If you read the comment to the question, you should know why.